# Does adding open sets to a basis for a topology give a basis for that same topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis for a topology $\mathcal{T}$.

Say we add any number of open sets to $\mathcal{B}$, giving rise to a new family, $\mathcal{C}$.

Will $\mathcal{C}$ be a basis for $\mathcal{T}$?

**My attempt:** For every $U \in \mathcal{T}$ and $x \in U, \ \exists C \in \mathcal{C}$ such that $x \in C \subset U$.

This because $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{C}$.

Hence, $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis for $\mathcal{T}$.

I thought there was a contradiction here, because it first seemed that generating a topology $\mathcal{T}'$ by taking all unions of basis elements $C \in \mathcal{C}$ could yield $\mathcal{T}' \supsetneq \mathcal{T}$.

However, that can't happen, since each new open set we are adding can be expressed as a union of basis elements $B \in \mathcal{B}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it’s entirely correct.

Comment: Yes.  $C$ does not add any more information since every element of $C$ is already a union of elements of $\mathcal{B}$, as you pointed out.